# Degeneracy of momentum eigenstates in relativistic quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

Let's take QED as a paradigmatic example of Poincaré-invariant and interacting field theory. Thanks to traslational invariance we derive momentum conservation and hence we can define states which are eigenstates of both momentum and energy. I was wondering about what we can say regarding their degeneracy

Comment: In QFT momentum isn't an operator, therefore it makes no sense to speak of their eigenstates.

Comment: Instead, it is an operator! With eigenstates and all that...

Comment: related: [One particle states in an interacting theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/264991).