# Confusion on the proof of Goldstone’s theorem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, hilbert-space, symmetry-breaking, goldstone-mode

I amd reading a proof Goldstone’s theorem in Zee's QFT book. On page $228$, Zee presents the proof as follows.
The conserved charge $Q$ is given by
\begin{equation}
Q=\int d^D\vec{x}J^0(t,\vec{x}).
\end{equation}
In the next, he gives a state ket $|s\rangle$ as
\begin{equation}
|s\rangle=\int d^D\vec{x}e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}}J^0(t,\vec{x})|\Omega\rangle.
\end{equation}
It can be shown $|s\rangle$ is the eigenstate of momentum operator $P^i$(see the footnote On page 228). Finally Zee concludes that when we set $k$ to be $0$, $|s\rangle$ has zero energy and can be interpreted as particle(massless).

Here is my confusion: when can we interpret a ket $|\cdot \rangle$ as particle in QFT? Can we pick arbitary eigenstate of momentum operator $P^i$ and regard it as particle? Is there any standard definition for this point?

Comment: possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/264991/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/306426/84967

Comment: Yes, of course. (Incompletely localized) eigenstates of momentum  in QFT are particles, speeding chunks, or excitations... Tony doesn't make that clear? Particles move in momentum space, relativistically.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Tony? which page of his book?

Comment: Tony stands for Anthony. Unfamiliar with that book. Try a mainstream QFT text, like  [Tong](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/two.pdf).